# Line inside input on active

Tags: html

How to delete this inside border on active on input element ?

[image: border inside input]

Answer (score 1):

It is `focus` and actually not a border but the `outline`

```css
#name:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
  
  <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required
       minlength="4" maxlength="8" size="10">
       
   </body>
 </html>
```